# Usb 3.0 > 2.0 flash drive transfer speed

Tags: usb

While writing from usb 3.0 to a usb 2.0 flash drive is the transfer speed choked down to the max capacity of the 2.0 flash drive?

Comment: Yes;  USB 2.0 devices connected to USB 3.0 are limited by the USB 2.0 specification

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I suspected as much and have ordered a usb 3.0 drive.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the USB Backward Compatibility functionality, whenever you have multiple USB versions in a chain (USB2 Drive with USB3 Port, USB1 Printer with USB3 Port etc) - the transfer speed will always be at the slowest speed in the chain.

In your situation:

- USB3 Card can work at up to 5Gb/s
- USB2 Drive can work at upto 480Mb/s

Therefore, data will transfer at upto 480Mb/s as this is the quickest speed that all devices in the chain can support.  Get a USB3 Drive and since the cable, port and drive can all support USB3, the transfer rate will go up closer to the 5Gb speed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your USB 2.0 Port will not (magically) become of a higher bandwidth when transferring data from or to a device with a higher bandwidth.

Comment: You might want to clarify your answer.  The question is about a USB 2.0 device being connected to a USB 3.0 your answer currently talks about the inverse situation.

Comment: I am using a usb 3.0 card with usb 3.0 cable. The only usb 2.0 component is the flash drive.